MUI X accessing value in sx prop in gauge element gives me undefined / null
I'm using the MUI X Gauge to display a value and want to have the color of the Gauge arc depend on the value. For example if the value is too low I want to make it red, if it's just right green, if it's too high red etc.
The way I got it half working is using nested tenary operators in the sx prop accessing the fill property. I can use a variable in the state but if I want to use "value" it won't work.
This is what I have tried:
<Gauge width={100} height={100} value={12}
  startAngle={-110}
  endAngle={110} 
  valueMin={10}
  valueMax={40}
  sx={(theme) => ({
    [`& .${gaugeClasses.valueArc}`]: {
      fill: `${value < 15 ? '#0000ff' : '#ff0000' }`,
    },
  })}
/>

this gives me the error "value is not defined".
Then I have tried to pass value along with theme:
<Gauge width={100} height={100} value={12}
  startAngle={-110}
  endAngle={110} 
  valueMin={10}
  valueMax={40}
  sx={(theme, value) => ({
    [`& .${gaugeClasses.valueArc}`]: {
      fill: `${value < 15 ? '#0000ff' : '#ff0000' }`,
    },
  })}
/>

this doesn't crash but doesn't work as intended. I ended up discovering it was null
[`& .${gaugeClasses.valueArc}`]: {
  fill: `${value == null ? '#0000ff' : '#ff0000' }`,
},

this gave me a blue bar.
What am I doing wrong here?
Edit:
Anyway, here's my working solution with a variable from state


<Gauge width={100} height={100} value={testval}
  startAngle={-110}
  endAngle={110} 
  valueMin={10}
  valueMax={40}
  sx={(theme) => ({
    [`& .${gaugeClasses.valueArc}`]: {
      fill: `${testval < 15 ? '#0000ff' :
           testval < 28 ? '#008000' :
           testval < 30 ? '#ffa500' :
           '#ff0000'
          }`,
    },
  })}

/>



